# GWT error when uploading file with SingleUploader

Tags: gwt, file-upload, gwtupload

I used SingleUploader for uploading file in my Google Web Toolkit project which is deployed to Tomcat. Whenever I tried to upload a file, it prompted this error: "Error, your browser has not sent any information. Please try again or try using another browser". However, in development mode, I can upload without any error. What can be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using GWT 2.7 with the latest GWTUpload Library (1.0.3). First you need a server side session object - check that this is enabled (JSESSIONID in Tomcat - check the headers of the request).

Moreover there are some issues with the SingleUploader (in FF) so try to switch to the normal Uploader and use `uploader.setMultipleSelection(false);` to make it a "SingleUploader".

If this is not working provide more information about your configuration/implementation please.